# URL rewrite for Root domain

Tags: wordpress, magento, url-rewriting

I have magento on my root domain with wordpress integration, so currently I have url like www.myurl.com/blog and I don't to display /blog in my url. the result url should be www.myurl.com/

is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to settings>general and change the site url to www.myurl.com and the wordpress url to www.myurl.com/blog then COPY not move the .htacess and index.php files into the root directory. This should use wordpress as the site for the domain now. In order to access the backend you will still need to go to www.myurl.com/blog/wp-admin